# Preserve newlines when pulling text from xml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

**My XML (pulled from a .docx):**

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:rPr/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr/>
    <w:t>0 things and stuff</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:rPr/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr/>
    <w:t>1 things and stuff</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

**Desired output:**

```
0 things and stuff
1 things and stuff
```

**Actual output:**

```
0 things and stuff1 things and stuff
```

I tried to use the lxml package in hopes that their tostring method with pretty_print would produce better results than the default xml package.

In researching the problem, I've come across the explanation that using method='text' in tostring causes all formatting to be lost.

**My code:**

```
tree = etree.fromstring(xml_content)
docx_text = etree.tostring(tree, method='text')
```

I've tried using pretty_print=True, tostringlist, and tounicode. Am I just looking for a feature that doesn't exist in this package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a parser that understands all the business logic of the docx xml semantics, e.g. that because the two text lines are in separate paragraphs they should be displayed on separate lines.

You could try to do this yourself, but I'd recommend using something like [`docx`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx) -- or at least have a look at the `getdocumenttext()` function in the source for one way to go about this.

```
import os
from docx import getdocumenttext
from lxml import etree

# get `xml_content` from word doc...    

tree = etree.fromstring(xml_content)
paragraphs = getdocumenttext(tree)
print(os.linesep.join(paragraphs))
# Result: 
# 0 things and stuff
# 1 things and stuff
```

**Update:** For fully reproducible example, see below

```
import os
from docx import getdocumenttext, opendocx
from lxml import etree

## load the xml tree from word document ##
# EITHER:
tree = opendocx('/path/to/my/file.docx')

# OR
xml_content = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
 <w:body>
  <w:p>
   <w:r>
    <w:t>0 things and stuff</w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p>
   <w:r>
    <w:t>1 things and stuff</w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
 </w:body>
</w:document>
"""
tree = etree.fromstring(xml_content)
##

paragraphs = getdocumenttext(tree)
print(os.linesep.join(paragraphs))
```

Comment: Oh my. I think I love you. Thank you!

Comment: sure thing, glad I could help

Comment: I actually could not reproduce your results and got paragraphs = [] with no exceptions or errors. Please show the full version of what you did, for example you must of have imported lxml and I had to modify the example xml string to read it without error so exactly what xml string did you use?  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I modified my example to work with the `xml_content` var that astrimbu already had with his example and the `etree`, but you are right the import should be there... and yeah I recreated word docx to include the header to get it to parse with lxml w/o error.  Will update.